# How to make the animation run every x seconds

Tags: javascript, loops, time, requestanimationframe

I want an animator that if I have like this

```
index = 0;
function animate() {
    index++;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

But how do I make it so index++ is every x second?
so if x is 5 for example index += 1 every 5 second/ the animation makes a loop every 5 second.

Comment: `animate` can accept an argument that `requestAnimationFrame` provides: it’s a timestamp that you can use to calculate when 1 second has passed. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) like this

```js
index = 0;
function animate() {
    index++;
    console.log(index)
    //requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

setInterval(function(){  
  animate();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should help you

```
let start = Date.now();

function foo() {
    if(Date.now() - start > 5000){
    console.log('hit')
   start = Date.now()
}
 requestAnimationFrame(foo);
}

foo();
```

Comment: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) provides a timestamp as an argument to `foo`. There’s no need to use `Date.now`.

Comment: Fair, I was just winging it but you are certainly right.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up for the setInterval() function in js.
Here's a link to begin with
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I don't understand how it works, I tried this `index = setInterval(function() {index += 1}, 5000);`